# Center image inside div + resize and keep proportion of image

Tags: css, image, resize, center, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to center an image vertically inside a div - while keeping the proportions of the original image and only allowing it to be inside the div.

The original image source will change dynamically - it could be any size in theory: 200x150, 500x100, 500x500 etc.

What I have so far is this:

```css
.outer {
    position: relative;
    background: gray;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: gold;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}

.inner img {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 150px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQwI_CFh8BfnYAn6pL7Pe1AX_LuxrvEs4HqL2qWNPoTvESUwj5hdw">
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example - I want it to look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7nPt.png

Is it possible with css?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add following to the image

```
 margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
```

full code:

```css
.outer {
    position: relative;
    background: gray;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: gold;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}

.inner img {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 150px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQwI_CFh8BfnYAn6pL7Pe1AX_LuxrvEs4HqL2qWNPoTvESUwj5hdw"
  </div>
</div>
```